# how to run fastapi app from different path

Tags: heroku, fastapi

my repo directory looks like

```
src/
notebooks/
web/
  one/
  two/
     app/
```

when I am under `two` I can lunch my `fastapi` app using

```
uvicorn app.app:app --reload --host=0.0.0.0 --port=7000
```

however, I am going to deploy my model on heorku and the Procfile should be at the main path. I know I have to make a Procfile and add

```
web: uvicorn app.app:app --reload --host=0.0.0.0 --port=7000
```

but I can't run the app from other folders. It would give the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

*UPDATE*

the output of `find web/two/app` is as following
[image]

so when I run  `uvicorn web.two.app.app:app --reload --port=7000`

the error is
[image]

Answer (score 6):

You have to provide the entire path from root to the app. In your case it should look like this:

`uvicorn web.two.app.app:app --reload --host=0.0.0.0 --port=7000`

Comment: when I do that it says ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

Comment: I replicated your exact folder and file structure and it does work for me. Given the path to `app.py` is `./web/two/app/app.py` and you declared your FastAPI app as "app" this works as expected. Please check that you are in the root directory and the names of the folders along this path, as well as the entry point file name which in your case should be "app.py".

Comment: thanks @Mark I updated my question with comments to your points :-)

Comment: I see, glad my solution works. The problem has switched howeve, to how imports work in Python. Can you share the code of `app.py`.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/BAXE1m here is the code - can you see it ?

Comment: I also have the same issue, running from a /src dir 
`uvicorn src.server:app` cannot find all the modules in my app which have paths declared from src/

Answer (score 2):

You can run your app from different path by following below command:

`uvicorn --app-dir <path-to-your-app/main file> <main-file-name>:<object-of-FastAPI> --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 7000`

In your case it will be (assuming you are writing below command in web/ dir):

`uvicorn --app-dir  ./two/app app:app --reload --host=0.0.0.0 --port=7000`